# How to pass and use a generic object in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have multiple methods that each return an Object.

```
public objA myCall(string[] args)
{           
    webAPI myAPI = new webAPI();
    returnData = myAPI.callApi("http://localhsot/api", args , "POST");

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myObj));

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(returnData))
    {
        objA result = (objA)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And

```
public objB myCall(string[] args)
{           
  webAPI myAPI = new webAPI();
  returnData = myAPI.callApi("http://localhsot/api", args , "POST");

  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myObj));

  using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(returnData))
  {
      objB result = (objB)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

      return result;
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is consolidate these into one method using generics.  This way I can pass in the object that I would like returned.  I've never used generics before and need a little help.  This is what I have tried:

```
public T myCall<T>(ref T myObj, string[] args)
{           
  webAPI myAPI = new webAPI();
  returnData = myAPI.callApi("http://localhsot/api", args , "POST");

  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myObj));

  using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(returnData))
  {
      myObj result = (myObj)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

      return result;
  }
}
```

But when I put this into Visual Studio, I get get an error saying that "myObj" is a variable but is used like a type.  If you have had experience with this and are willing to help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @PoulBak That's a misleading comment.  The problem is the way it's used later, not how it's referenced as a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there

```
public T myCall<T>(string[] args)
{           
  webAPI myAPI = new webAPI();
  returnData = myAPI.callApi("http://localhsot/api", args , "POST");

  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

  using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(returnData))
  {
      T result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

      return result;
  }
}
```

And then you call it by passing the type as the generic constraint.

```
var result = myCall<objA>(someArguments);
```

---

*On a side note (and also my opinion) `objA` is not a good name for a type.*

Comment: lol, yea, I just named it that on this site to hide my actual code. :)

Comment: Follow up question:  I'm trying to add a try catch in case something goes wrong.  How can I return an empty object "T"?  I've tried:
  T return = new T; 
but this give me an error.

Comment: @TheBigOnion - `return default(T);`

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will give that a try.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove from parameters `myObj` and change it in the body of method to `T` like this

```
public T myCall<T>(string[] args)
{           
  webAPI myAPI = new webAPI();
  returnData = myAPI.callApi("http://localhsot/api", args , "POST");

  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

  using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(returnData))
  {
      T result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

      return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Igor, thx, missed it looking only on the first two methods =)